# Execute sqflite operation on separate isolate in flutter and synchronously

Tags: flutter, sqflite, dart-isolates

I am trying to execute sqflite operation in compute to run in another isolate and the result is returned should show in listview builder so I need to create it sync, but in my case the sqflite operation run at last after listview builder execution.

Please help me with this and thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can add the sample code for your need

Comment: any sqflite query returns `Future` so i dont think you need to run it in a separate isolate

Comment: I am trying to create shopping app in which list of items are showing by listview builder list is getting from API call what ever the items in the cart it should be show like added in listview, when try to check product id of item is in sqflite it return at the end of listview build creations that's why item of list not showing added instead it show add to cart on button.

Comment: @Vidhey How did your run sqflite on a separate isolate using compute

Answer (score -2):

The simple thing need to do is use future builder in sqflite DB operations.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to show the result of asynchronous operation in [ListView builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) you just need to wrap ListView widget with [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Entity>> {
  future: compute()
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

    final listData = snapshot.data!;

    return ListView.builder(
      // properties
    );

  }
}
```